# How to group and sum values from array of objects?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects (`responses`), which can contain any number of objects (i.e. indeterminate number of `rounds` and `questions`), in any order. The objects inside will be similar:

```js
responses [
  {
    name: "personA"
    uniqueId: "abcd"
    roundNumber: 0
    questionNumber: 0
    score: 1
  },
  {
    name: "personA"
    uniqueId: "abcd"
    roundNumber: 0
    questionNumber: 1
    score: 1
  },
  {
    name: "personA"
    uniqueId: "abcd"
    roundNumber: 1
    questionNumber: 0
    score: 0
  },
    name: "personB"
    uniqueId: "efgh"
    roundNumber: 0
    questionNumber: 0
    score: 1
  },
  {
    name: "personB"
    uniqueId: "efgh"
    roundNumber: 0
    questionNumber: 1
    score: 0
  },
  {
    name: "personB"
    uniqueId: "efgh"
    roundNumber: 1
    questionNumber: 0
    score: 1
  }
]
```

How would I group and sum the `scores` depending on the values of the objects? More specifically I would like to take all the objects for `personA` (using their `name` and `uniqueId` fields), then sum up the scores by `roundNumber`. Then repeat the process for every player.

Example of flow:

- Sum the score of `personA` for `roundNumber: 0`, and save that.
- Sum the score of `personA` for `roundNumber: 1`, and save that, etc...
- Repeat for `personB`, then `personC`, etc...

The resulting array could be something like:

```js
sorted = [
  {
    name: "personA",
    uniqueId: "abcd",
    scores: [2, 0]
  },
  {
    name: "personB",
    uniqueId: "efgh",
    scores: [1, 1]
  }
]
```

I've looked at for loops, indexOf, map, filter, reduce, and I'm struggling hard with this one because the amount of `players`, `rounds`, or `questions` could be any amount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a standard approach for grouping and increment the value of a certain index.

```js
var data = [{ name: "personA", uniqueId: "abcd", roundNumber: 0, questionNumber: 0, score: 1 }, { name: "personA", uniqueId: "abcd", roundNumber: 0, questionNumber: 1, score: 1 }, { name: "personA", uniqueId: "abcd", roundNumber: 1, questionNumber: 0, score: 0 }, { name: "personB", uniqueId: "efgh", roundNumber: 0, questionNumber: 0, score: 1 }, { name: "personB", uniqueId: "efgh", roundNumber: 0, questionNumber: 1, score: 0 }, { name: "personB", uniqueId: "efgh", roundNumber: 1, questionNumber: 0, score: 1 }],
    grouped = Object.values(data.reduce((r, { name, uniqueId, roundNumber, score }) => {
        r[uniqueId] = r[uniqueId] || { name, uniqueId, scores: [] };
        r[uniqueId].scores[roundNumber] = (r[uniqueId].scores[roundNumber] || 0) + score;
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with a `reduce` method. Also, I make the `scores` as an object with `roundNumber` index which can help you to define which score gained for which round.

```js
const responses = [{ name: "personA", uniqueId: "abcd", roundNumber: 0, questionNumber: 0, score: 1 }, { name: "personA", uniqueId: "abcd", roundNumber: 0, questionNumber: 1, score: 1 }, { name: "personA", uniqueId: "abcd", roundNumber: 1, questionNumber: 0, score: 0 }, { name: "personB", uniqueId: "efgh", roundNumber: 0, questionNumber: 0, score: 1 }, { name: "personB", uniqueId: "efgh", roundNumber: 0, questionNumber: 1, score: 0 }, { name: "personB", uniqueId: "efgh", roundNumber: 1, questionNumber: 0, score: 1 }];


const res = responses.reduce((a, c) => {
 if (!a.find(x => x.name === c.name)) {
     a.push({name: c.name, uniqueId: c.uniqueId, scores: {[c.roundNumber]: c.score}});
 } else {
     let index = a.findIndex(x => x.name === c.name);
     if ( index > -1) {
         a[index].scores[c.roundNumber] = (a[index].scores[c.roundNumber] || 0) + c.score;
     }
 }
 return a;
}, []);

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution solution runs in `N (log N)` which is the most efficient thing you can do. assuming you have a lot of items in the responses array

```
const responses = [......];
var group = [];
responses.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a.name === b.name)
        return a.uniqueId < b.uniqueId;
    return a.name < b.name;
}).forEach(item => {
    if(group.length === 0 || group[group.length - 1].name !== item.name || group[group.length - 1].uniqueId !== item.uniqueId) {
        group.push({
            name: item.name,
            uniqueId: item.uniqueId,
            scores: { [item.roundNumber]: item.score }
        })
    } else {
        if (group[group.length - 1].scores[item.roundNumber]) {
            group[group.length - 1].scores[item.roundNumber] += item.score;
        } else {
            group[group.length - 1].scores[item.roundNumber] = item.score;
        }
    }
});

group = group.map(item => {
    const scores = [];
    for( const i in item.scores ) {
        scores.push(item.scores[i]);
    }
    return {...item, scores};
});
```